# Last step in 'django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer'

Tags: python, django

I`m trying to add a browse server to CKEditor and I use django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer 0.1.0

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer/0.1.0

But I don't understand the last step- "Add FilerImage button to you CKEditor configuration."

I think its a 'filebrowserImageBrowseUrl', so  I add it to CKEDITOR_CONFIGS, but I don't know what value to put.

Answer (score 0):

To add FilerImage button to CKEditor panel you should edit file settings.py of your application and add 'FilerImage' to CKEDITOR_SETTINGS like:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
...
"toolbar": [
...
[ 'FilerImage', ...
```

Note: to be sure the name of button is not changed in current plugin's version - you can check library file at {lib}/ckeditor_filebrowser_filer/static/djangocms_text_ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/filerimage/plugin.js and find the line "editor.ui.addButton" with actual button's name (looks like "editor.ui.addButton( 'FilerImage', {")

Comment: Having the same Issue here: This solution is not working for me. No error message, no button.